# Get boostrap position-fixed class to go away on smaller breakpoint

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm writing React, and I thought I'd find something to disable a side nav that will be fixed except on smaller screens. Something like `position-fixed-lg` but only find `position-fixed` in the bootstrap 4 classes.

Is there an easy way, or does it call for a media query? Thank you.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-4 position-fixed">
          <Header/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
          <Main/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It would require a media query

Comment: There is no such functionality in bootstrap 4. You will have to create it with mediaquerys.